# How to make a larger rabbet by hand?

Tags: hand-tools

I'm looking to make a larger rabbet into an 6' 4x4 similar to the below picture - but I don't have a circular saw.

[image]

Or would it be better to simply attach a 2x4 or 1x4 to the main piece?

Comment: You want to cut a 3" rabbet into a 4x4? How deep do you want it?

Comment: *"Or would it be better to simply attach a 2x4 or 1x4 to the main piece?"* Yes I think this would be vastly preferable. In addition to other advantages (saves wood, can use smaller and cheaper pieces so probably end up cheaper) building can actually yield a stronger end result since as we know glue joints are stronger than the wood itself if they're done right — fresh, flat joint surfaces, plenty of glue, clamp **hard**.

Comment: I agree with most of the other posters that gluing up two pieces is probably the way to go, but I think it's also worth pointing out that the hand tools you'll need to do this (a rabbet plane would be your best bet) are going to cost you more than a circular saw anyways.

Answer (score 5):

You have three choices that I can think of:

- The old fashioned way.

  - You will need a plough plane of some sort.
  - Use it to cut a channel 3¼" deep with the far edge where you need it.
  - Use a chisel to remove most of the waste
  - Finish off the rest of the rebate with an ordinary plane.
- The easy way

  - Buy a circular saw.  They are fantastically useful and not that expensive.
- The cheap way

  - Removing a 3"x3¼" rebate from a 4x4 is throwing away an *enormous* amount of wood.
  - Instead buy 4x¾ and 3¼x1 and glue/screw them together.
  - You may need to buy 4x1 for the latter piece and use a ripsaw or plane to trim it to size (or get the woodstore to cut it).  Don't try to use a cross-cut saw.
  - If you are going to attach this rabate to another 4x4, I would actually try and make it out of 5x3¾ and 8x¾ (it will give you much more to fasten to).

Final point:  Beware that 4x4 planed timber is not 4" across - it will be less (it was originally 4" rough-sawn timber that has been planed).  Bear this in mind when composing your profile by adding bits together.

---

**EDIT** [Graphus](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/users/243/graphus) points out that finding a plough-plane which goes 3" deep may be tricky (an old wooden plough without a fence .  An alternative is a rebate (or rabbet) plane.  With that you would have to plane away the whole of the groove, but  3"x3¼"x6' of wood is a *lot* of planing.  I would still try to remove as much as possible with a chisel (or even by drilling holes).

Comment: Good comprehensive Answer. Just one thing, I believe ploughs can't commonly cut grooves 3"+ deep (and it would be a big struggle to do a 6' channel dead straight in common softwoods) so I think a rebate/rabbet plane is more applicable to the first suggestion.

Comment: @Graphus - good point.  Updated